# using SWIG with C++

Tags: c++, python, swig

HI all

I am trying to use SWIG to export C++ code to Python.
The C sample I read on the web site does work but I have problem with C++ code.

Here are the lines I call

```
swig -c++ -python SWIG_TEST.i
g++ -c -fPIC SWIG_TEST.cpp SWIG_TEST_wrap.cxx -I/usr/include/python2.4/
gcc --shared SWIG_TEST.o SWIG_TEST_wrap.o -o _SWIG_TEST.so -lstdc++
```

When I am finished I receive the following error message

```
ImportError: ./_SWIG_TEST.so: undefined symbol: Py_InitModule4
```

Do you know what it is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you aren't linking to the Python runtime library.  Something like adding `-lpython24` to your gcc line.  (I don't have a Linux system handy at the moment).

Answer (score 1):

you might try building the shared library using `gcc`

```
g++ -shared SWIG_TEST.o SWIG_TEST_wrap.o -o _SWIG_TEST.so
```

rather than using `ld` directly.

Answer (score 1):

As Mark said, it's a problem linking to the python library.  A nice way to get hints as to just which flags you need to successfully link can be gotten by running `python-config --ldflags`.  In fact, a particularly painless way of compiling your test is the following:

```
swig -c++ -python SWIG_TEST.i
g++ -c `python-config --cflags` -fPIC SWIG_TEST.cpp SWIG_TEST_wrap.cxx
gcc --shared `python-config --ldflags` SWIG_TEST.o SWIG_TEST_wrap.o -o _SWIG_TEST.so -lstdc++
```

Note that `python-config` isn't perfect; it sometimes gives you extra things, or conflicting things.  But this should certainly help a lot.